# HP LasterJet P2035 not mapping on remote desktop

Tags: remote-desktop, hp, printing

I am connecting from a Windows 7 Pro laptop to a remote 64bit Windows 2008 R2 server via Remote Desktop. My local laptop has a networked HP LaserJet P2035 printer set as the default printer. When I connect to the server, the local (networked) HP printer does not get mapped on the server.

I've installed the 64bit drivers from HP for the printer and was able to create a test printer on the server itself using the correct driver (HP LaserJet P2035) priting to a file. I've also checked the Printer under Local Resources tab on my Remote Desktop client.

Does anyone know where else I should check to get my local printer to make to my remote desktop session?

Comment: What does your event log tell you? There should be an event for the failure in the System log.

Comment: Instead of mucking with printer drivers try enabling Remote Desktop Easy Print on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looked into Easy Print... wasn't that easy. I checked the System Log and found the problem. The printer was expecting a different driver than the actual printer driver for the printer. Installed the printer driver from the log, worked like a charm.

Thank you for your help.